# How to clear state in botkit 4 conversation

Tags: botkit, botkit-4

We have built a bot using [**botkit v4**](https://botkit.ai/docs/v4/) and we are using it with Facebook messenger.

We want to clear the state on a specific `facebook_postback`.

I tried the following but nothing is working.

```
bot.controller.storage.delete(message.user)
```

I did not find any proper references in the documents as well. any help will be appreciated.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/storage?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#delete-string---

Answer (score 0):

Storage.delete method takes a list of identifiers, so correct syntax is

```
bot.controller.storage.delete([itemId]);
```

Also you need to discover correct format for itemId,
I have an example from websocket controller and it looks like this:

```
websocket/conversations/USERID-USERID/
```

The final syntax would look like this:

```
const itemId = 'facebook/conversations/' + message.user + '-' + message.user + '/';
await bot.controller.storage.delete([itemId]);
```